# Is there any embeddable NoSQL Document Database with C# drivers?

Tags: c#, mono, document-storage, nosql

RavenDB, right.. ;-)
But it needs to run under mono (=> windows, nix, osx)

#### Requirements

- embedded
- NoSQL document database
- official (or at least maintained / well documented) c# drivers
- mono support
- open source / free

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net this should help you make your choice.